# swap a word in a matched line with another line (two lines after)

Tags: text-processing

I read a lot of close question, but didn't find a solution to my problem.

I have a text file with the current structure :

```
## 誰 <!--QR2Y;1;2023-04-18-->
だれ
quelqu'un, qui, quel 

田中さんてだれですか。
« Qui est ce M. Tanaka ? » 

## 歌う <!--T2B7;1;2023-04-18-->
うたう
chanter, réciter

ピアノに合わせて歌う。
« Chanter accompagné d'un piano. »
```

The aim is to swap and reorder information as :

- get the japanese word in the line starting with `##` and replace it with the line two-line after.
- remove this line two-line after
- and put this japanese word under this modified `##` line

To get this result

```
## quelqu'un, qui, quel  <!--QR2Y;1;2023-04-18-->
誰
だれ

田中さんてだれですか。
« Qui est ce M. Tanaka ? » 

## chanter, réciter <!--T2B7;1;2023-04-18-->
歌う
うたう

ピアノに合わせて歌う。
« Chanter accompagné d'un piano. »
```

The structure is always the same. The variable parts are the `<!--X0X0;0;000-00-00-->` that always change, and sometimes is not there at all.

It seems that `sed` is a solution, but I'm kinda lost in the documentation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with `awk`

- Feed `awk` two times with the same file
- In the first run:

  - If `##` found, save `jw` (japanese word) and the corresponding `fw` (french word) as an array with the row number (`NR`) as index.
- In the second run:

  - check if the row number exists in `fw` and then replace the japanese word with the french word and print the corresponding japanese word afterwards.
  - Print all lines excluding the ones with the french words we just placed.

```bash
awk '
  NR == FNR && /^##/ { jw[NR]=$2; nr=NR; }
  NR == nr+2 {fw[NR-2]=$0}
  NR>FNR {
    if(FNR in fw) { $2 = fw[FNR]; print; print jw[FNR]; }
    else { if (!(FNR-2 in fw)) print; }}
' file file
```

Output:

```
## quelqu'un, qui, quel  <!--QR2Y;1;2023-04-18-->
誰
だれ

田中さんてだれですか。
« Qui est ce M. Tanaka ? » 

## chanter, réciter <!--T2B7;1;2023-04-18-->
歌う
うたう

ピアノに合わせて歌う。
« Chanter accompagné d'un piano. »
```

Comment: Perfect ! I just slightly modified it to use it as a script file with arguments, replacing ``file`` by ``$1``, and adding ``> $2`` for paste the output on a text file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a single-pass solution:

```c
awk '/^##/ {hdr=$0; j1=$2; getline; j2=$0; getline; fr=$0;
           sub(/## [^<]+/, "## " fr " ", hdr); print hdr; print j1; print j2; next } 1' input
```

- This will identify the header line via the `##` starting pattern and store it in the variable `hdr`.
- It will then extract the first japanese part `j1` as being second space-separated field (I assume they don't contain spaces) of that line.
- It will read the next line and buffer it full as second japanese part `j2`.
- It will again read the next line and buffer it as the french translation `fr`.
- Then, it will substitute the first japanese part in the buffered header with the french translation, print the modified header and both japanese parts, each on their own lines. It will then skip execution to the next line.
- All other lines are printed unmodified thanks to the (seemingly stray) `1` outside of the rule block.

Comment: [avoid the use of `getline()`](http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline) when it's not absolutely required

Comment: @GillesQuénot In this case, I actually consider it necessary for the single-pass solution. Although the example input is nicely formatted, I have too often seen the separating empty lines being omitted at some point after all, so that the "paragraph mode" approach shown e.g. in Ed Morton's answer - while certainly more elegant - ultimately failed where in theory it should have worked :(

Answer (score 1):

In 1 pass using any awk that supports multi-byte characters (for the Japanese words):

```
awk '
    BEGIN { RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS=OFS="\n" }
    /^##/ { split($1,a," "); $1=a[1] " " $3 " " a[3]; $3=$2; $2=a[2] }
1' file
## quelqu'un, qui, quel  <!--QR2Y;1;2023-04-18-->
誰
だれ

田中さんてだれですか。
« Qui est ce M. Tanaka ? »

## chanter, réciter <!--T2B7;1;2023-04-18-->
歌う
うたう

ピアノに合わせて歌う。
« Chanter accompagné d'un piano. »
```

If you didn't have blank lines between records and so `RS=""` wouldn't work then you could do (still 1 pass, just buffering 3 lines for every `##` block):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\n" }
/^##/  { lineNr=1; buf = $0; next }
lineNr { lineNr++; buf = buf RS $0 }
lineNr == 3 {
    $0 = buf
    split($1,a," "); $1=a[1] " " $3 " " a[3]; $3=$2; $2=a[2]
    lineNr = 0
}
!lineNr
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
## quelqu'un, qui, quel  <!--QR2Y;1;2023-04-18-->
誰
だれ

田中さんてだれですか。
« Qui est ce M. Tanaka ? »

## chanter, réciter <!--T2B7;1;2023-04-18-->
歌う
うたう

ピアノに合わせて歌う。
« Chanter accompagné d'un piano. »
```

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```
perl -00pe 's/^(##\s*)(.*?)(\s*<!--.*-->\n)(.*)\n(.*)/$1$5$3$2\n$4/' your-file
```